# Can't login to Magento admin after migration

Tags: admin, migration

I recently set up a new Linux server for development

Then I went to my production Linux server that has my current magento website.  I modified the configuration to use a new url like `https://developmentarea.mysite.com` then i cleared out the magento cache.  Then I zipped up all the magento files and mysqldump the database.

i moved everything over to the new linux server.  Installed the magento site.  I am able to see the product pages on this new development area.

When I go to the admin area, and I'm asked to login, I am unable to.  I put in my username and password, press submit, and i'm redirected back to the login page.  I notice that once i'm redirected back to the login screen, there is no error message saying I entered the wrong username or password.  I see in the browser url that this bit has been added `https://dev.mysite.com/index.php/admin/index/index/key/4727dbc6df408ace4070a39aa72f9289/`.  This leads me to suspect that I perhaps I actually did login, but was kicked back out.

Does anyone know why I can't login to the admin area even though the database should be a copy of the production but with all the urls changes?

Comment: Did you delete everything in /var/session/ ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue a while back - These steps fixed it for me

1) In **PHPMyADMIN** run this query:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code = 'NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

2) Clear `/var/cache/*` and `/var/session/*`

3) Clear your browser `cache/cookies`

If that doesn't work make sure session and cache directories are writeable

Answer (score 0):

Try this mysql query and check domain name is correct for all entries or not.

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` = "web/cookie/cookie_domain" or `path` LIKE "web/secure/base%" OR `path` LIKE "web/unsecure/base%"
```